# How do you know if the value is the same for the following rows in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this kind of data:

| Break | Start | Stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

I'm trying to create a new column so that I have the start and end **only** if there are five 1 in a row when Brake == 1 like this:

| Break | Start | Stop | NewCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | Start |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | Stop |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Should the columns `start` and `stop` be ignored? What happens if there's six breaks in a row? Based on what you have now you can create the new column so it's "Start" when the column `Start` == 1 and "Stop" when the column `Stop` == 1

Comment: @JuanC I thought adding the Start and Stop columns might help people visualise. You need at least 5 breaks in a row so if there are more it's the same. So the new column is created and takes the value Start at the beginning of the first break and takes the value Stop at the time of the last break only if there are at least 5 breaks in a row.

Comment: Could you provide better example data? As provided now, there are multiple ways to obtain you desired output but not all will meet your conditions. Providing slightly more complex example data highlighting the caveats will help people help you faster (ie, put some rows with `Break == 1` that don't satisfy the condition)

Answer (score 1):

I've added some more rows to your data

```
df=structure(list(Break = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Start = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stop = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

using a loop

```
tmp=rle(paste(ifelse(df$Start==1,"A",""),ifelse(df$Stop==1,"B",""),sep=""))

for (i in seq(2,length(tmp$lengths)-1)) {
  if (tmp$values[i-1]=="A" & tmp$values[i]=="" & tmp$lengths[i]>=3 & tmp$values[i+1]=="B") {
    tmp$values[i-1]="Start"
    tmp$values[i+1]="Stop"
  }
}

df$NewCol=rep(tmp$values,tmp$lengths)
df$NewCol[!(df$NewCol %in% c("Start","Stop") & df$Break==1)]=""
```

and the result

```
   Break Start Stop NewCol
1      1     1    0  Start
2      1     0    0       
3      1     0    0       
4      1     0    0       
5      1     0    1   Stop
6      1     0    0       
7      0     1    0       
8      0     0    0       
9      0     0    0       
10     0     0    0       
11     0     0    0       
12     0     0    1       
13     0     0    0       
14     1     1    0       
15     1     0    0       
16     1     0    0       
17     1     0    1       
18     1     0    0       
19     1     0    0       
20     1     0    0       
21     1     0    0       
22     1     0    0       
23     1     0    0       
24     1     0    0       
25     1     1    0  Start
26     1     0    0       
27     1     0    0       
28     1     0    0       
29     1     0    0       
30     1     0    0       
31     1     0    1   Stop
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried your answer yet but your first version before the edit works perfectly well!

Answer (score 0):

using `rle`

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
    mutate(NewCol = with(rle(Break),
                map2(lengths,values, ~{
                    if(.x >= 5 && .y == 1)
                        c("Start",rep("", .x - 2), "Stop")
                    else
                        rep("", .x)
                }) |>
                flatten()))

##>   Break Start Stop NewCol
##> 1     1     1    0  Start
##> 2     1     0    0       
##> 3     1     0    0       
##> 4     1     0    0       
##> 5     1     0    1   Stop
##> 6     0     0    0       
##> 7     0     0    0       
##> 8     0     0    0       
##> 9     0     0    0
```

Comment: While this satisfies the example data provided by the OP, it doesn't work when extending it. Try it on `df <- data.frame(Break = c(rep(1, 5), rep(0, 4), rep(1, 5)),
                 Start = c(1, rep(0, 8), 1, rep(0, 4)),
                 Stop = c(rep(0, 4), 1, rep(0, 7), 1, 0))` and you'll see it adds a "Stop" in the last column where `Start` and `Stop` both are 0. The OP needs to provide better example data.

Comment: My interpretation of OP's comment, is that I can ignore `Start` and `Stop` columns and rely  only on `Break`. Or not?

Comment: I don’t think so (I can be wrong) but it seems like when they state “…start and end only if there are five 1 in a row when Brake == 1” that the distance between `start == 1` and and `stop == 1` need to be >= 5 rows (and `Break == 1`). Perhaps they can clarify

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df<- data.frame(Break = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0))
df$Start <- 0
df$Stop <- 0
v<- c(1,1,1,1,1)
x<-which(df == v)
df$Start[x[seq(1,length(x),5)]] <- 1
df$Stop[x[seq(5,length(x),5)]] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it *Start* and *Stop* can be ignored? Either way this solution doesn't need them so can be added if desired. I extended the example to show edge cases if more or less then 5 1's exist.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(Break, default=T) != Break)) %>% 
  mutate(is = cumsum(Break) %% 5, 
         newcol = case_when(is == 0 & Break == 1 ~ "Stop", 
                    is == 1 & Break == 1 & lead(is, 4) == 0 & 
                      lead(Break, 4) == 1 ~ "Start", 
                    TRUE ~ ""), 
    is = NULL) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 18 × 2
   Break newcol 
   <dbl> <chr>  
 1     1 "Start"
 2     1 ""     
 3     1 ""     
 4     1 ""     
 5     1 "Stop" 
 6     0 ""     
 7     0 ""     
 8     1 "Start"
 9     1 ""     
10     1 ""     
11     1 ""     
12     1 "Stop" 
13     1 "Start"
14     1 ""     
15     1 ""     
16     1 ""     
17     1 "Stop" 
18     1 ""
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Break = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This may by a solution too:

```
# install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
    df<-structure(list(
      Break = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
      Start = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
      Stop = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)),
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))                                                                                                         
    dt <- as.data.table(df)
    dt[Break == 1, dbatch := {
      nbatch = ceiling(.N / 5)
      head(rep(seq(nbatch), each = 5), .N)
      }]
    dt[, NewCol := fcase(
      sum(Break) == 5 & .SD[, Start[1] == 1 & Stop[5] == 1] & Start == 1, "Start",
      sum(Break) == 5 & .SD[, Start[1] == 1 & Stop[5] == 1] & Stop == 1, "Stop",
      default = ""
    ), by = dbatch]

    Break Start Stop dbatch NewCol
 1:     1     1    0      1  Start
 2:     1     0    0      1       
 3:     1     0    0      1       
 4:     1     0    0      1       
 5:     1     0    1      1   Stop
 6:     0     0    0     NA       
 7:     0     0    0     NA       
 8:     0     0    0     NA       
 9:     0     0    0     NA       
10:     1     1    0      2       
11:     1     0    0      2       
12:     1     0    0      2       
13:     1     0    1      2       
14:     1     0    0      2       
15:     0     0    0     NA       
16:     0     0    0     NA       
17:     1     1    0      3  Start
18:     1     0    0      3       
19:     1     0    0      3       
20:     1     0    0      3       
21:     1     0    1      3   Stop
    Break Start Stop dbatch NewCol
```